# How to align multiple divs inline using inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```css
.block {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #a2a2a6;
}

.color {
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.red {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.green {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.yellow {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My website style guide</h1>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Colors</h2>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="blue">Blue</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="red">Red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="green">Green</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class=yellow>Yellow</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code displays 4 colored blocks that are displayed horizontally. I want to display them all in one line(and if in the future more colored blocks were added they would start new line and then another etc)

I have tried

```css
.color {
display: inline-block;
}
```

or same with `.block`
but it does not seem to do it. I understand that inline-block is supposed to be used but dont understand where exactly im supposed to put it. please offer a solution which does not change classes of the original code.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is – here's [a fiddle containing your code](https://jsfiddle.net/j9wmvnd5/) with the `display: inline-block` rule applied to `.color`, and it shows the coloured blocks in one line, as would be expected. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. There is no closing `</div>` for `.block`.

Close that div and `display: inline-block;` on `.color` will work.

```css
.block {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #a2a2a6;
}

.color {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blue {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.red {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.green {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}

.yellow {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: cetner;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My website style guide</h1>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Colors</h2>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="blue">Blue</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="red">Red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class="green">Green</p>
    </div>
    <div class="color">
      <p class=yellow>Yellow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```